# Авторизация с выбором 4-х пар параметров

Tags: php, авторизация

Страница авторизации(входа в личный кабинет).

Есть 3 поля :

```
<input1> // сюда можно ввести логин, email, телефон, №карты
<input2> // пароль
<input3> // пин-код (участвует только если авторизация через № карты)
<button> // кнопка отправки данных
```

Возможная авторизация:

1. Логин (input1) и пароль (input2)
2. Email (input1) и пароль (input2)
3. Телефон (input1) и пароль (input2)
4. №карты (input1) и пин-код (input3)

Как такую вещь сделать если через input можно только 1 параметр имени передать?
И вообще такое возможно только с 3 полями? Если да, то куда копать?

Comment: Пин-код - это тоже пароль. Ну как бы...

Comment: Ладно пусть будут 2 инпута. Вопрос в том как передать данные для проверки в БД, если name в инпуте как бы 1.

Comment: Я навскидку вижу два варианта. Первый - совместить поля input2 и input3 в одно поле, обозвав его "пароль/пинкод", после чего программно пытаться понять, что же введено в поле input1 (если потребовать строгого формата ввода - это несложно, скажем, запретить "@" в логине и потребовать первый символ строго букву, а телефон/карту можно различить по длине). Второй - дополнить набор комбобоксом, где пользователь должен выбрать тип авторизации (заодно можно менять в зависимости от выбора подписи к инпутам и даже шаблон ввода логина).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял  можете использовать этот пример:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Здесь соединение на базы данных

    $res = mysql_query('Select * from users where (mail="'.$login.'"  or username="'.$login.'" or phone="'.$login.'") and password = md5("'.$password.'") LIMIT 1');

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($res);


    if($rows>0){


        //Ваш код
        //Редикерт на главной страницы
    }else{

        echo "Ошибка неверный логин или пароль";
}

?>
```

Вот простой 
[пример авторизации на PHP + MYSQL](https://htmlweb.ru/php/example/avtorizacija2.php)

Comment: Спс Akina и Y.Ghorbani. Вместе я думаю эти 2 способа как раз сработают.

Comment: Возникла другая проблема. Вот код : **$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `bd_users` WHERE ('login' = '".$login."''  or 'email' = '".$login."'' or 'phone' = '".$login."'') and 'pass' = '".$pass."'");
    if($res == FALSE){
         echo "error";
    }else{       
       echo "tadam";
    }**           какие бы значения в поле логин и пароль я не выбирал вылетает только "error". В бд несколько заполненных позиций. Ни на 1 комбинацию логина и пароля "tadam" так и не вылетело.